# How do I add a different header to every boto3 request?

Tags: python, boto3, botocore

I need to be able to dynamically add a custom header based on the object hash. I have previously been able to find examples of how to add a constant header to every request sent, but that's not adequate for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

For use cases where you want to dynamically set a header, you can do the following:

```py
event_system = client.meta.events

# Moves the custom headers from the parameters to the request context
# This is done because later in the processing of the request, there is
# a parameter validation step, which doesn't allow for custom arguments.
def process_custom_arguments(params, context, **kwargs):
    if (custom_headers := params.pop("custom_headers", None)):
        context["custom_headers"] = custom_headers

# Here we extract the headers from the request context and actually set them
def add_custom_headers(params, context, **kwargs):
    if (custom_headers := context.get("custom_headers")):
        params["headers"].update(custom_headers)

event_system.register('before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject', process_custom_arguments)
event_system.register('before-call.s3.PutObject', add_custom_headers)

custom_headers = {'If-Match' : '"3858f62230ac3c9ff15f300c664312c63f"'}

client.put_object(Bucket="my_bucket", Key="my_key", Body="my_data", custom_headers=custom_headers)
```

This registers 2 handlers into the event system, one to move the custom headers from the request parameters into the request context, and another one to set it. This is done to circumvent the function argument validation that boto3 performs.